# Разметка дисков в Linux (Debian 10)

Tags: linux, диск

В компьютере установлено два твердотельных накопителя - один на `64 GiB`, второй - на `32 GiB`.

Необходимо: создать четыре раздела на основном диске (boot, root, home и swap). Домашний раздел нужно объединить в `RAID1` массив со вторым диском. При этом необходимо шифрование всех разделов, кроме, разумеется, boot.

sda (LVM):

- 1 GiB - boot
- 4 GiB - swap (K)
- 27 GiB - root (K)
- 32 GiB - home (K, RAID1)

sdb (LVM):

- 32 GiB - home (K, RAID1)

Сперва добавляю boot, потом настраиваю шифрование двух томов, после настраиваю LVM (группа состоит из одного диска - sda) и сами разделы на первом диске. Но в таком случае не выходит настроить RAID.

Подскажите, как именно нужно конфигурировать разделы? В каком порядке?

Comment: Честно сказать, создание lvm'а на шифрованных разделах я не настраивал, так что на вскидку не скажу, какие там будут подводные камни... а в остальном: 1)я бы `boot` уменьшил хотя бы до 512M или даже до 128M... дальше создай два pv для lvm'а, и объедини их в одну vg... swap и root создай на первом /dev/sda, а для хомика организуй raid средствами lvm'а...